# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, matrix, plot

I am struggling with plotting this function, so basically i have to make a x vector and f vector for my first function, plot it, and then create a vandermonde matrix. i am struggling with the first part of this code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-6,6,10) #test interval

    def main():
        Vt = Vandermonde(x)

        print(Vt)

    def f1(x): 
        f1 = 1/((x)**2+1)
        return f1
        print(type(f1),f1.shape)
        print(f1)


    plt.plot(x,f1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You define a `f1` function, but I don't see you run it.  Don't use the same name for a function and variable (even if Python allows, it will confuse you).

Comment: hey , when i run it, i get an error saying "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)"

Comment: Did you understand my comment?  You have **not** calculated `y`; `f1` is still the function, not an array produced by the function!

Comment: so how do i make this function into an array and make it have the same dimensions as my x? sorry I'm a bit new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace *plt.plot(x,**f1**)* with *plt.plot(x,**f1(x)**)* because *f1* refers to the name of the function  so it is a python object  but what you want to do is to call that function with x as parameter.